# Instructions for how to lay out the Mac OS X and Linux versions of Electron apps?

Tags: electron

I've just spent a very long time looking through everything on https://electron.atom.io/docs/ but I cannot find any mention of how to put the files for Mac and Linux. Only Windows, which I already have set up.

I remember that NW.js had such instructions, which I followed in the past, but it's obviously too ridiculous to accept that I should have to look at a competitor's manual to figure out how to distribute Electron apps.

I remember that at both Linux and Mac had some very fancy/weird packaging need, very unlike Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) which would help you with generating packages for all of the mentioned systems (with auto-update and other goodies).

You can also take a look at [electron-boilerplate](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate) to see how it can be nicely implemented (this boilerplate has a release command that allows you to generate packages).

Comment: Well, thanks, but I don't wanna use "black boxes" that I don't fully control. I prefer knowing exactly what happens, so I'd really appreciate instructions on how things should be laid out instead of having to rely on a third-party tool. (Although I will still look into it.)

Comment: As expected, I couldn't understand a thing about either of those tools. What they are, how you use them, what the hell they're talking about, etc. I just wanna know how they want you to structure the files for each platform. Is that too much to ask for? Basic documentation? (Or I guess I could just forget about Mac/Linux.)

Comment: I would still recommend using a tool for it even for Windows. To do a proper install on Windows you still need to call an installer with a package signed by your private code signing key, then the installer needs to add registry keys for the app and for its uninstaller, you also need to make sure you have a proper version of the Electron bundled with the installer (x86 or x64), bundled icons in the resources of the installer etc. It's better to leave it all to a tool (NSIS or WiX on Windows). Similar to other OS'es.

Comment: Maybe it seems that way to you, but I find those tools to be massively confusing and I just don't like them. I want to know exactly what happens in the whole build process. I already have an installer script and all for Windows. I want the information -- not some black box tool that will die in two weeks when the developers lose interest.

Answer (score 0):

For the mac version you can use electron packager to generate a .app file then you can use [appdmg](https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg) to generate a .dmg

For the linux version you can use electron packager to generate a executable although it comes with lots of other files.

I've tried [electron-installer-debian](https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-debian) but I couldn't install the output .deb

Comment: What is "electron packager"?